# Error occurred when installing php-mcrypt on Centos 7

Tags: centos, php-mcrypt

I'm completely new to Linux in general and using Centos as a server. I tried to install the `php-mcrypt` extension through yum, but i'm only receiving errors. I have some difficulty interpreting what the problem might be in this case. What should I do and how can i fix these errors?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally found a solution after hours of researching right after I submitted my question. This worked and I was able to install php-mcrypt.

```
sudo yum clean all
sudo yum install epel-release
sudo yum install php-mcrypt
```